# Adobe Acrobat using javascript to check a radio button when another is checked

Tags: javascript, radio-button, adobe, acrobat

I'm a beginner in Adobe Acrobat and javascript.

I have to create a form for my company. When the user select a department (this is a radio button), it should select automatically the signature group (which is another radio button.

This is what i got so far:

```
var a = this.getField("OtherCompanyDAN"); 
var b = this.getField("alias-dentsu"); 
if(a.isBoxChecked(0)) 
    b.checkThisBox(0,true); 
else 
    b.checkThisBox(0,false);
```

I know this code is supposed to work with the `CheckBox`, I have no clue how to translate it with `radio button`.

Could you help me ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have two radio buttons with differents choices for each. I would like to link them: when one choice of the first radio button is selected (Mouse up action) I would like a specific choice of the second radio button to be selected. 

I can easily do it with checkboxes but I don't know how to do it with radio buttons because radio buttons choices  have the same Name.
Here is what I do with checkboxes : 
var a = this.getField("OtherCompanyDAN");
var b = this.getField("alias-dentsu");

if(a.isBoxChecked(0))
b.checkThisBox(0,true);
else
b.checkThisBox(0,false);

Comment: Post the code, please.

Comment: The code I use for the checkboxes is the following. However it doesn't work with radio button because I guess the name is the same for the all choices. 

var a = this.getField("OtherCompanyDAN");
var b = this.getField("alias-dentsu");

if(a.isBoxChecked(0))
b.checkThisBox(0,true);
else
b.checkThisBox(0,false);

Comment: I have edited your question in order to add the code.

Comment: Only check boxes can be unchecked. A radio button cannot be unchecked using this method, but if its default state is unchecked (see defaultIsChecked) it can be reset to the unchecked state using the resetForm. method of the Doc.